# How to make a highchart display data with ordinal set to true

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a highchart that looks like this with the `ordinal: false`: [image: chart with <code>ordinal:false</code>] As you can see the `xAxis` has some dates that have no data. So by setting `ordinal:true` on the `xAxis` I expect that dates without data are not shown. And this is what I get when I do that: [image: chart with <code>ordinal:true</code>] Now the problems with this is:

- *dates* on the `xAxis` are not shown
- the data on the *minimum* and *maximum* points of the `xAxis` have only half of the column bar displayed (check image 2 left and right)
- the tooltip does not show all the series'
- When I add stockchart functionality, the `navigator` doesn't show the dates.[image: chart in stockchart mode]

What I would like is:

- A look similar to image 1 but with only dates that have data
- Stock chart functionality on the chart.

I have a **JSFiddle** setup [here](http://jsfiddle.net/musale/hxds0wtq/5/)

Comment: I think that you problem may be connected with your data. Right now your data is not sorted and it can cause this issue. Here you can find an example with sorted data: http://jsfiddle.net/hxds0wtq/8/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński what element in the data did you sort? the dates?

Comment: Yes, I have sorted your dates.

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński great! I have sorted them and it's worked like a charm. Thanks mate!